# How to store and read passwords using Bcrypt

Tags: spring, passwords, bcrypt

I have a problem using BCrypt.
I want to store user passwords in a safe way and therefore, I am using Spring's BCrypt to store the passwords encrypted.
The problem I am facing now is that BCrypt generates a random salt and of course, the password cannot be decrypted.
But how can I handle a login then?

```
private PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

public String encryptPassword(String password) {
        String encryptedValue = encoder.encode(password);
        Assert.isTrue(encoder.matches(password, encryptedValue));
        return encryptedValue;
}
```

What do I need to do to make sure the passwords are matching when the user is entering his credentials?

```
String encryptedPassword = encryptionGenerator.encryptPassword(loginCredentials.getPassword());
```

And then I try to read from DB with hibernate

```
FROM Login WHERE email = :email AND password = :password AND email_confirmed = 1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure the passwords are matching when the user is entering his credentials, No need to encode password again to validate encoded password which you got from database.

**BCryptPasswordEncoder** class  will match password by string values only.

I tried following way and its working for me. If your concern is to authenticate a user, you can try following way:

`@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public void validateUser(User user) {

    // get User entity from database using your user repository
    final User currentUser = userRepository.findByEmailId(user.getUserName());

    final BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    if (pwEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), currentUser.getPassword())) {
        // user password is correct
    }
    else{
        //user password incorrect
    }

}



public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
        
        @Query("FROM Login WHERE emailId = :emailId")
        User findByEmailId(@param("emailId") String emailId);
    }`

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. Sometimes I am just blind